# How to connect old stereo system to pc?

Tags: stereo, speakers, computer, connector

I want to playback my mp3 files from pc through my old stereo speaker system

The problem is, it can play from sources like radio, CD, tape and usb. It also has a jack called 'phone', so it is possible to listen through headphones (from those usb/cd's/tapes)

On the back, speakers are connected through basic electric cables (there are 4 ports: Rleft, Rright and Lleft, Lright):

[image]

And, that's all I have, do You think there is a way to connect this system to for playback from pc filemanager/browser/YouTube etc.?

EDIT: I figured out I can connect those speakers separately from control center, by using external amplifier. Well, that obviously would work! But that's too expensive for me at the moment. 
I would love to use internal amplifier (which is built-in in stereo system control system)

And here is my system, Thomson CS97
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "Tape" input is effectively identical to "Aux". It is almost certainly an ordinary line-level input. It should be trivial to connect the speaker or headphone or line output from your computer to your stereo box.  It would be enormously helpful to show us a photo of the BACK of the amplifier unit.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was thinking - his wording is confusing, are these "sources" S/PDiff, Coax, Phono Jacks... or are they _internal sources..._

Answer (score 1):

You should look if there is a jack called "AUX", it will take an external source as an input for your amplifier, otherwise no easy way to do it.

Comment: Ahaa, and there is no such a thing :/ As I said, as a 'source' it can take CD, USB or Tape, but not AUX

Comment: @DarekBuryński I saw some online manual, I confirm no AUX input, so a solution could be hacking the circuit, but you should be very very confident with electronics.